# how to migrate email data from parallel plesk to cpanel

Tags: cpanel, migrate

We have plesk hosting account now we want to migrate to cpanel,approx 5gb mail data in plesk account how to direct transfer Email data from plesk to cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate whole account through cPanel migration tool

OR

You can submit migration requesto to cPanel support team. They will help you on this. Here are the some useful information about this. 
https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/cPanel+Migration+Services+and+Guides

Comment: I submited request they asking for root access and we don't have root access. only cpanel.